# NHibernate. Bidirectional properties

Tags: c#, nhibernate, associations, bidirectional

For example if there's a class:

```
class Post
{
    public String AuthorUrl { get; set; }
    public Byte[] AuthorImg { get; set; }
}
```

Would it be a better practice to put to `Post` class Author's `Url` and `Image` instead of placing `Author/User` class itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a question about object orientation rathernthan nhibernate? It would be better to have an author class, and thusnan author property in the post class and put the url and image properties in the author class indeed.